# Project template missing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Today in one of the computer i installed visual studio 2010 professional edition, and successfully installed. But in my new project template "Asp.net MVC 2 website" is missing. Also I'm not able to open an already created MVC 2 project also. I'm also having MVC 2 installed with VS 2008 Sp1 in the same machine and is working fine. I uninstalled and installed again, the same is happening. Please help me out of this..

Comment: Five answered questions, and none accepted answers is a little unbalanced.

Comment: @kiamlaluno do you have any suggestions plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried downloading MVC 2 RTM separately following the Visual Studio 2010 install? **[Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en)**

Alternatively, did you have any of the betas or previews of MVC2 installed prior to installing Visual Studio 2010? You'll need to uninstall these.

Comment: Tried the above not working out...Also when i start visual studio i'm getting some package load failed error messages.

Comment: Tried with 5 installations. Still got stucked

Comment: Launch the VS2010 Setup. Then, remove the Visual Web Developer item and launch setup again to install it.

Answer (score 1):

When installing or modifying the installation of Visual Studio 2010 ensure you have 'Visual Web Developer' ticked. (see image below). If you just install C# you will not get MVC 2.

[image]

Comment: Visual web developer is ticked. The problem is because of that vs 2008 and vs 2010 is sharing the MVC 2 dll's.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new website or project? I just did a fresh install of Professional and MVC 2 is only available under projects.