# VS2010 ASP.NET Starter Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, templates

I am trying to create an ASP.NET web site, and I would like to start with the template here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/26/starter-project-templates-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

I have used this template in the past, but for some reason the computer that I'm currently using does not have it. Actually, when I choose *File->New Web Site...*, I get a lot less options than what are shown on that site (e.g. I cannot make an "AJAX Server Control").

Can anyone direct me to how I can add these features into Visual Studio? Do I need to install a plugin?

I am using VS2010 with SP1 installed. Windows XP with .NET 4.0 installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that you target the correct version of the framework in the new project window?

Comment: Have a look [this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/tp52b). try that option !!!

Comment: @SteveB Yes, I tried with both .NET Framework 4 and everything else (3.5, 3.0, 2.0).

Comment: Which edition of VS are you using?

Comment: @SteveB VS2010 Professional, Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Comment: There are some case (Microsoft loves making simple things complex) where the templates are not properly deployed. You can try to run `devenv.exe /setup` from an elevated command line. This will rebuild the templates cache

Comment: @SteveB This did not work for me, but I think you are on the right track. After I followed your suggestion, I got an error when I reopened Visual Studio, which gave me a clue. I was able to locate the template that I want in this directory: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\Web\CSharp\1033\WebApplication40.zip`.  Not the optimal solution, but I think I'll just copy that folder and put it wherever I want to save my website. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, this worked after I restarted. If you want to make it the answer, then I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some case (Microsoft loves making simple things complex) where the templates are not properly deployed.

You can try to run `devenv.exe /setup` from an elevated command line. This will rebuild the templates cache. This will extract all the template files from the template archives.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the options you picked during install you may have a lot less options available.

You may need to install those extra projects, you can either reinstall VS and pick the available options during install or go to File> New Project.. and select the 'Online templates' button on the left and have a search for the project you want to install.

Comment: Hm..I believe that I chose every option at install, though. I reinserted the VS2010 disc, and this appears to be the case. (I cannot add any more features).

Comment: I think your answer applies in some cases. Here is a related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373899/project-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Could you screenshot your current list of item or list them that you get for .net framework? List would be better as imgur is blocked here.